# How to set active slide for bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to reset carousel to first slide after closing it.

I am closing carousel using data-dismiss.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

`Property .carousel(number)`

Where number is the slide number.

Or use data attribute  ->

```
data-slide-to="2"
```

Where "2" is place of the slide

For more info: 
[BootStrap JavaScript Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)